# How can I improve this question about Siri?

Tags: discussion

A few days ago I asked "[How can I turn off Siri's joke responses?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/287161/how-can-i-turn-off-siris-joke-responses)"

I thought this was a perfectly legitimate question. It's on-topic, not subjective, and (I think) pretty clear what I'm asking. It's not intended as a complaint or an invitation to discussion, just a simple "how do I do this" question. I understand that the answer may be "you can't currently" or "nobody knows", although I hope it's not.

My question received several helpful comments and a possible answer. The score is currently -2, which means at least two people thought it was a bad question. Obviously no one but them knows why they voted, but I'm pretty surprised by this. I thought it was a decent question. Is there something obviously wrong that I'm missing? Or if not, is there anything I could change to make this question acceptable?

Comment: I upvoted it - at least it's back to a flat zero now :/ [& no, I don't see anything wrong with it either]

Answer (score 4):

I've had a look at the question and, to be honest, don't see any major problems with it.

Obviously there's no way to know what the users who downvoted you were thinking, but I had a look and see they were all before you changed the title, so who knows if that played a role.

In this case it may be best to move on and forget it. For what it's worth, I don't get the joke responses you get when I use Siri to set a timer, so that in itself makes the question valid in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks you for taking a look.